# How to prevent SQL Server user from running system stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure

Is there a way to prevent a given user from running system stored procedures in SQL Server (Azure) at the database level, and if yes what is the SQL configuration statement?

The user in question has a read-only permission on the database, and I would like him to be able to execute regular SQL queries (`SELECT`), but not running procedures.

Thanks

Edit: The user 'readonlyuser' was created with a newly created login, then assigned a permission as follows: EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readonlyuser';

Comment: How did you create this user? Are you sure their only role is read only? Are you sure they *can* execute system procedures?

Comment: `EXECUTE` and `SELECT` are separate permissions. If you granted right to user to `SELECT` on schema, table, or database, that user will only have `SELECT` permission. Make sure you have not added user to any roles that have EXECUTE or other permissions that you don't want user to have.

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand thanks for your help. I first created the login, then the user, then I assigned user permission as follows: EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readonlyuser';

When I tried running a random system sp with that user, it seemed that the sp was executed (although the parameter was not correct).

Comment: Hi @SaUce thanks for your help also. Please check my previous comment and tell me what you think

Comment: What system procedures are you trying to prevent being executed and why?

Comment: I removed my answer for I have failed to cover 'system', by default when user is created that user is granted rights to execute system stored procedures. some SP will only return partial or no results.

Comment: @MartinSmith all SP, because there is no need for the user to execute them - this removes eventual security threats.